# Sending CORS POST request from javascript web-service client return http 405 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, rest, cors

a couple days ago, I implemented a web-service (both client & server). Client was sending request with `XMLHttpRequest()` and it was fine. However, today I'm trying to change sending request from it to jquery's $.ajax(); way.

For this purpose here this is my client side function:

```
function ajaxQuery(){
  $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:8080/recommender/sider/drugs',
   method:'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify({"uris":["SampleName1", "SampleName2", "SampleName3"],"limit":100 }),
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
}).done(function(data) { console.log(data) });
}
```

And this is the filter that I use in the server side  :

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse alteredResponse = ((HttpServletResponse) response);
            addCorsHeader((HttpServletRequest) request, alteredResponse);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void addCorsHeader(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-By");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, when I sent this POST request I got the http 405 error and this is the screenshot of my erroneous part.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wqlqkbnqwnjllx/Screenshot%202015-08-18%2011.27.29.png?dl=0

What should I do to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually sending a GET request, not POST. You used `method` in your `$.ajax`. I suspect you have a jQuery version below 1.9.0, and should use `type` instead.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   type:'POST',
   ...
```

As per the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> An alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change datatype as **jsonp**

```
{dataType: 'jsonp'}
```